# Passing a Perl Hash by reference plus scalar variable

Tags: perl, hash, reference

I'm trying to pass from Main.pl to a sub (in ReadConfigFile.pm) a hash by reference and a scalar value.  The scalar variable is the path to a config file and once this file is opened I want to fill a hash with some of its values.  How do i pass a hash by reference and a scalar so that I then have the hash values available to use in Main.pl

I have done a lot of reading but cant get this to work.  I realise i cant do  = @_; in my sub as that is creating a new hash.

Ive tried following the prototype method, this fills the hash ok but back in Main.pl the hash is empty.

Main.pl

```perl
# Read the config file.  Return 3 scalars and a hash
my %apps;
my ($schema, $directory, $staticFile) = readConfigFile(\%apps, $configFilePath);

my %app_list = %apps;  # ive tried this in, out and in a variety of states

foreach my $name (sort keys %app_list) {
    print "\nMAIN $name";
}
# this is empty
```

ReadConfigFile.pm

```perl
sub readConfigFile (\%$) {
my ($apps_ref, $configFilePath) = @_;

# also tried 
# $apps_ref = shift but then configFilePath is empty
# linearray is each line from open config file split by :

$apps_ref{$lineArray[1]}{id} = $lineArray[1];
$apps_ref{$lineArray[1]}{name} = $lineArray[2];
$schema = $lineArray[1];
$directory = $lineArray[1];
$staticFile = $lineArray[1];

return ($schema, $directory, $staticFile);
```

configFile.txt

```perl
APP:1101:ACTIVITY
APP:1102:EVENTS
APP:1103:PERFORMANCE
APP:1104:LOCATION
STATIC_FILE:static_file.sql
SCHEMA:CAASS
DIRECTORY:CAASS
```

I want to get the 3 scalar variable returned and the hash so i can use them throughout Main.pl and pass to other subs.

I have also tried passing in just the configfilename and returning 4 variables, the 3 scalars and the hash.

I expect someone will crack this in minutes but i just cant work out the combination of \ and @ and % and $ to make it work.

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Edit 1:
Main.pl

```perl
my %apps;
my ($schema, $directory, $staticFile) = readConfigFile(\%apps, $configFilePath);

foreach my $name (sort keys %apps) {
    print "\nMAIN $name";
}
```

ReadConfigFile

```perl
sub readConfigFile () {
my $apps_ref = shift;
my $configFilePath = $_[0];
#Fill It
$apps_ref{$lineArray[1]}{id} = $lineArray[1];
$apps_ref{$lineArray[1]}{name} = $lineArray[2];

# This shows results
foreach my $name (sort keys %apps_ref) {
    print "\nreadConfigFile   $name";
}
```

But the values arent coming back into Main.pl

edit 2:
So im still interested in how the above can be made to work.  But ive attacked it a different way and it works

Main.pl

```perl
my ($schema, $directory, $staticFile, %apps) = readConfigFile($configFilePath);

foreach my $name (sort keys %apps) {
    print "\nMAIN $name";
}
```

ReadConfigFile

```perl
sub readConfigFile () {
my $configFilePath = $_[0];
my %apps;
#Fill It
%apps{$lineArray[1]}{id} = $lineArray[1];
$apps{$lineArray[1]}{name} = $lineArray[2];

foreach my $name (sort keys %apps) {
    print "\nreadConfigFile   $name";
}

return ($schema, $directory, $staticFile, %apps);
```

Both sets off output show.

Comment: `use strict;` `use warnings;`

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!!! It would have found the problem

Comment: All these errors have come to my attention as i've added use strict; and use warnings;  Without turning them on it was working so there would be no question !

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit 'pass by reference' in Perl*. Everything is passed the same way - as a list of scalars, by alias (thus passing a hash itself will instead pass the list of its keys and values*). But you can create a reference, pass it, and then dereference it to use it - and references can be copied around without copying the underlying structure.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %hash;
my $ref = \%hash;
my $copy = $ref;
$copy->{a} = 1;
print "$ref->{a}\n"; # also 1
```

References will maintain their referenced structure after a `my (...) = @_;` or `my $foo = shift;` assignment in a subroutine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub foo {
  my ($ref, $key) = @_;
  $ref->{$key} = 42;
}

my %hash;
foo(\%hash, 'foo');
print "$hash{foo}\n"; # 42
```

See https://p3rl.org/REF for the relevant documentation on Perl references.

Since you are already passing a reference, there is no need for your `(\%$)` prototype: you can just remove it from the subroutine definition.

*except sort of with prototypes, but it's better to avoid them in most cases.

Comment: I undetstand your code but it gets a bit more confusing for me when the variables are being passed to a sub and back again.  Could you expand  on your answer please and show me how to get the 2 variables out of a sub.  Thanks

Comment: @DavidJanes I added an example, does that help? Make sure not to use `()` either in the subroutine definition, this is still a prototype and does not do what you want.

Comment: Re "*There is no implicit 'pass by reference' in Perl*", Quite the opposite, everything is passed by reference. (You gotta keep in mind that only scalars can be passed to subs, though.)

Comment: @ikegami That's what I was trying to say but perhaps explained badly - there's no feature to do so, because it always occurs, but only with the scalars passed.